# Save the state of a counter

Tags: android, counter

In my application I have a counter that increases with the use of certain buttons. My problem is that I would like to save the state of the counter. When I close the application and reopen this resets, and I want to show the result that there was before closing the app

code:

```
TextView Display;
int counter = 0 ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);


Button example:

counter = counter-3;
Display.setText(""+counter);
```

Comment: Use Shared Preferences.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android?rq=1

Comment: @Farnabaz op wants to save the value after app close and re-open the linked post does not help

Comment: shared preference could be good please give me an example of code thanks

Comment: @user3490452 its there in the docs and look at the api's and use them appropriately

Comment: Does not help thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to do that, depends on the application and its uses

You can

1. Use shared preferences (preferred as per your question)

   refer to
   [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)
2. Not a good practice but if you want you can save in a file.
3. Use Sqlite (tons of tutorial, e.g. [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/))

Comment: I could send the "number" from onPause and take that "number" to onResume.  I know sharedPreferences but I do not know how to make it work for this

Comment: Here add something like this
//your key can be string --"counter" and value as counter
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
  editor.putString(key,value);
  editor.commit();